# Delete elements from numpy ndarray using a mask

Tags: python, numpy

Sample problem:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(30).reshape(-1,10)
mask = np.ones((3,10),dtype=bool)
mask[[0,1,2],[3,4,5]] = False

y=x[mask]
#y.shape returns (27,)
```

I would like y.shape to return (3,9). Is there a builtin function that works for numpy ndarrays and returns same? My current solution simply rehshapes array:

```
y.reshape(x.shape[0],-1)
```

Comment: Please edit your question. What's the mask ? The size is incorrect.

Comment: Since a 2d mask like that can have differing numbers of `True` in each row (or column) it can't, in general, produce a 2d array.  So instead it produces a flat result.  It's up to you to reshape if you know that is possible.  `reshape` is a simple, fast operation.  Don't be afraid to use it.